# Trade marks or trademarks?

Tags: orthography, compounds, spacing

What is the correct format to use when referring to trademarks in British English? Is "trademarks" generally preferable?

I've seen both used in different contexts, the UK GOV page uses "trade marks", but I'm not sure. Trade marks looks a little scruffy to me.

Comment: If you [search the gov.uk site](https://www.gov.uk/search?q=%22trademark%22), there are some pages where it is spelled as a single word.

Comment: And if you look closely you can see some scuffs and scratches on the bottom from when I traded it to Kevin.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that both forms are in current use, almost equally, with a slight advantage to *trademark* as a single word.

[image: ngram of trademark and trade mark]

*trademark* in blue, *trade mark* in red. Note this graph is generated from British data alone.

Answer (score 0):

With the term being a legal construct, I would treat the government's presentation as authoritative.

Perhaps it looks wrong to you because you are American? In the US, the government does write it as [trademark](https://www.uspto.gov/).

---

**Edit:** The relevant statutes are available online for both [the United States](https://tfsr.uspto.gov/RDMS/TFSR/current) and [the United Kingdom](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1994/26). The difference stems from the laws as written, and "trade marks" is technically correct in the UK even though common usage may be trending toward the American version.

Comment: I'm a Brit, but I think I just prefer 'trademark'. I was also wondering whether or not this may have have been a British vs. American English phenomenon

Comment: Perhaps it is common to write it that way. In the US, our law is the Trademark Act, while in Britain it is the [Trade Marks Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_Marks_Act_1994).

Answer (score 0):

The form should be in the form that it is in your Trade Marks Act. In Australia it is two words, in America it is one. So when referring to the foreign mark we refer to American marks as being trademark but Australian as being trade mark.

But Google, for search engine rankings distinguishes them. So it depends on what use you are talking about as to which one you might use.

Comment: A link to your source, do you have? :)

Comment: I am not sure what link you want. I am a registered Australian Trade Marks Attorney [link] (https://eaglegate.com.au) and have been for over 10 years. I am also a trademarks lawyer. This is the convention we all follow. I am not sure it is written anywhere. But it should be logical that you use the words as the country does.

Comment: I see. In that case, it would help if you include that information in the answer body.